# Take values from one column to new column if conditions met in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe (df) like below with following columns

"Solved by me" column has index values "TRUE/FALSE". It says whether the ticket is solved by me or not.

```
row  Tkt.number  Group   solved.by.me
1    Tkt478111  Group A  FALSE
2    Tkt478111  Group B  FALSE
3    Tkt478111  Group C  FALSE
4    Tkt478111  Group A  FALSE
5    Tkt478111  Group A  FALSE
6    Tkt478111  Group X  FALSE
7    Tkt478111  Group A  FALSE
8    Tkt478111  Group X  FALSE
9    Tkt478145  Group A  TRUE
10   Tkt478145  Group A  TRUE
11   Tkt478145  Group B  TRUE
12   Tkt478145  Group B  TRUE
13   Tkt478145  Group B  TRUE
```

I would like to check the following conditions and store the results in new column **Moved.out.from**

**Conditions:**

1. If "Solved by me" is FALSE
2. If the ticket is moving out from one of the specified list of groups (say "grp_list" - Group A,B,C,D)and not coming back to the mentioned group

> ```
> row Tkt       Group   solved.by.me  Moved.out.from
> 1   Tkt478111 Group A FALSE   
> 2   Tkt478111 Group B FALSE   
> 3   Tkt478111 Group C FALSE   
> 4   Tkt478111 Group A FALSE   
> 5   Tkt478111 Group A FALSE   
> 6   Tkt478111 Group X FALSE   
> 7   Tkt478111 Group A FALSE          Group A
> 8   Tkt478111 Group X FALSE   
> 9   Tkt478145 Group A TRUE    
> 10  Tkt478145 Group A TRUE    
> 11  Tkt478145 Group B TRUE    
> 12  Tkt478145 Group B TRUE    
> 13  Tkt478145 Group B TRUE
> ```

Please note row 7 where "Tkt478111" is moving out from Group A (which is available in our pre-defined list) and not coming back but it is not true in row 5. Because it went out from group A and came back again. (group X is not available in pre-defined group list)

I'm new to R and do not know how to deal with it. Any ideas how to perform this? Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure someone will pipe up with a simple `dplyr`/`data.table` approach to the problem, but meanwhile, here's one way with `base` R:

```
df <- read.table(text='row  Tkt  Group   solved.by.me
1    Tkt478111  A  FALSE
2    Tkt478111  B  FALSE
3    Tkt478111  C  FALSE
4    Tkt478111  A  FALSE
5    Tkt478111  A  FALSE
6    Tkt478111  X  FALSE
7    Tkt478111  A  FALSE
8    Tkt478111  X  FALSE
9    Tkt478145  A  TRUE
10   Tkt478145  A  TRUE
11   Tkt478145  B  TRUE
12   Tkt478145  B  TRUE
13   Tkt478145  B  TRUE', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

grps <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

newdf <- do.call(rbind, 
                 lapply(split(df, df$Tkt), function(x) {
                   i <- which(x$Group %in% grps & !x$solved.by.me)
                   x$moved.from <- NA
                   if (length(i) > 0 && tail(i, 1) != nrow(x)) {
                     x$moved.from[tail(i, 1)] <- x$Group[tail(i, 1)] 
                   }
                   x
                 }))

row.names(newdf) <- NULL

newdf

#    row       Tkt Group solved.by.me moved.from
# 1    1 Tkt478111     A        FALSE       <NA>
# 2    2 Tkt478111     B        FALSE       <NA>
# 3    3 Tkt478111     C        FALSE       <NA>
# 4    4 Tkt478111     A        FALSE       <NA>
# 5    5 Tkt478111     A        FALSE       <NA>
# 6    6 Tkt478111     X        FALSE       <NA>
# 7    7 Tkt478111     A        FALSE          A
# 8    8 Tkt478111     X        FALSE       <NA>
# 9    9 Tkt478145     A         TRUE       <NA>
# 10  10 Tkt478145     A         TRUE       <NA>
# 11  11 Tkt478145     B         TRUE       <NA>
# 12  12 Tkt478145     B         TRUE       <NA>
# 13  13 Tkt478145     B         TRUE       <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks ! it's working but I'm getting numbers (1,35,31...) instead of Group name in Column "Moved.from".. :(

Comment: Your group column is a factor in that case. You can do `df$Group <- as.character(df$Group)` before running the other code.

Comment: I probably wouldn't recommend it, but sure. Change `x$moved.from <- NA` to `x$moved.from <- ''`